# Website title is only displayed when the mouse is moved

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a problem: the title of my website doesn't appear until the mouse is moved. On the phone only when your finger touches the screen. Does anyone have an idea what the problem is? I use the Inspiro Theme. Do you need more information?

This is my website: https://dev-friedl-bau.pantheonsite.io/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in your CSS and Class items looks like you may have a hover instance.

.site-branding

This could be your problem!